# php external js only for logged in users

Tags: php, javascript, security, external

I´m having a php file which checks if a user is logged in by session.

```
@session_start(); 
(@$_SESSION['loggedIn'] ? '' : die(''));
```

and if so outputs a lot of JS an HTML. To keep the overview I want to exclude all JS in a file.
My Problem is, that the JS is sending AJAX to a PHP file which querys DB content. For security reasons I want this JS only be accessible to logged in Users. Which would not be the case if I would just put it into an .js file and link to it.

My workaround was now to put all JS code in a php file whith a Session check at the beginning followed by the JS code.

```
<?php
@session_start(); 
(@$_SESSION['loggedIn'] ? '' : die(''));
?>

<script type="text/javascript">

        jQuery(document).ready(function () {

    //Start configuration
        jQuery("#menu").tabify();
    ...
```

And then include this with

```
<?php include_once('js/script.func.php');  ?>
```

Is this the way you would do it, or is there are better solution? (means prevent opening security holes or errors.)

kind regards,

tony

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep that's alright. But you might want to verify in the server side that the user is logged in as well (where the JS sends requests).